# Vuforia Area Target version 10-16-5 doesn't work with HL2

Tags: target, vuforia, area

Does anyone have Vuforia Area Target work with HL2, I have try multiple version even the latest 10-16-5 on Hololens 2 and it doesn't work. Just a simple scene with a cube as a child of an area target in the scene => built and deployed on hololens 2, doesn't work. The cube won't show up at all.
Of course, I do have MRTK, OpenXR and all the setting as instruct by vuforia here https://library.vuforia.com/platform-support/working-hololens-sample-unity and here https://library.vuforia.com/develop-area-targets/area-targets-unity

I have tried using Unity 2021.3.29, MRTK 2.8.3, and Vuforia 10-16-5 with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, HL2 is tested with Area Targets for all commercial releases. Using the latest release as an example, Area Targets will have been tested on the HL2 with Engine SDK 10.16.5 and Area Target Generator 10.16.5.

First suggestion is to use the latest versions of the [Area Target Generator](https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/tool) and the [HL2 Unity Sample](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/templates/packs/vuforia-hololens-2-sample-101553) (Engine SDK is packaged within). Then, follow the instructions documented in our library (as you've already referenced):

- https://library.vuforia.com/platform-support/working-hololens-sample-unity
- https://library.vuforia.com/develop-area-targets/area-targets-unity

If the above is still unsuccessful and you still believe it is a bug, then I suggest you open a bug report [here](https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine/).